# What will be the simple SPI sequence to transmit packet with cc1101

Tags: spi, radio

I'm trying to mimic behavior of my weather sensor with `esphome` and `cc1101`.

`rtl_433` detects it as:
https://github.com/merbanan/rtl_433/blob/master/src/devices/infactory.c

What should be put on `cc1101` SPI to send similar packet?

Comment: You need to look into what data your weather station transmits/receives. Nobody but you and the exceptionally kind are going to do that for you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a request to for a custom design.  Making such a radio transmit is a complex series of commands setting configuration and providing payload data, if you do not know where to start, you need to do your own research to find example code.  The mission of this site does not include either creating example code, or helping you find it.  When you have found the basic pieces of what you need, some questions about specific issues could be on topic.

Comment: Probably all the required info is in the `infactory.c`. About "custom design" acusation, it is not. It is a question what should be put on the SPI bus to mimic behavior of mentioned weather station. CC1101 have shitload of registers and no single tutorial how it should be used. That's why I'm asking here.